# Creating a projection Line with Parabola effect

Tags: unity, c#

friends.

I'm trying to achieve a effect that where when the enemy/player get close to the player/enemy a parabola is formed in direction to the enemy/player to represent that is target in that moment.

Something like that. Similar to ff12.

https://gfycat.com/gifs/search/final+fantasy+xii+zodiac+age+hunts

I've been trying to use LineRenderer until now. It's the best option for this?

Comment: How have you tried implementing this effect with a LineRenderer so far? How does the result differ from what you want? The clearer you can be about the specific problem to solve, the faster you can get good answers to solve it.

Comment: There are 3 ways I see, 1. you can use process same as `LineRenderer` works (not smooth if you have few points, might be performance heavy in some instances), 2. use dynamic mesh, a bent cylinder where vertices follow a path of some curve, 3. use a shader to achieve this effect. For a 3rd party asset to achieve this I recommend `Shapes` by `Freya Holmér`, not sure if you can achieve the exact effect with it but from what I know - you should be able to, you will have to dig into documentation about it.

Comment: @CandidMoon_Max_ Yes! I tried with that 3rd party "Shapes" and I could get the effect that I wanted. I used Slerp as a method to get that parabola effect.